# Does $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n |\ln a_n| < +\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n < +\infty$ and $a_n > 0$. dose
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n |\ln a_n| < +\infty$$ hold?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take, for example, $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n(\ln n)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Does it hold if $a_n = \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}$?